# Trying to use Selenium server with selenium-webdriver for node

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get a driver from a server with `selenium-webdriver` for node.

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer('server.com').
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
    build();
```

The driver if gives me back is not working at all. How can I be sure that I'm getting a valid driver back?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to do the same.  The answer below misses the point and just states the documentation... I have it running locally, I want to be able to fire if off on another server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a `server.start()` before building the driver?

An example from the [WebDriverJs - Using the Stand-alone Selenium Server](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Using_the_Stand-alone_Selenium_Server) page:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    SeleniumServer = require('selenium-webdriver/remote').SeleniumServer;

var server = new SeleniumServer(pathToSeleniumJar, {
  port: 4444
});

server.start();

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer(server.address()).
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
    build();
// ...
```

Comment: Faiz is correct, we can run it from node program itself and also, by running selenium server separately.